# Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order 12.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be the group of rotational symmetries of the regular tetrahedron. This is a group of order 12. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of the identity and the rotations which do not fix any vertex. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**A subgroup $H$ is normal if $gH=Hg$ $\forall g\in G$**

My question is, is this the only way to prove a subgroup is normal? By explicitly calculating the left and right cosets? I also know that the order of $H$ can be either 1,2,3,4,or 6 By Lagrange's Theorem but how would that imply that it is normal ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Number the vertices 1,2,3,4 and view $G$ as a subgroup of $S_4$. Then observe that conjugation preserves cycle structure.

Comment: Adding to Bungo, observe that it is isomorphic to $A_4$. Any normal subgroup must be union of conjugacy classes. Now apply Lagrange. (You would then deduce a unique subgroup of order $4$).

Comment: You can invoke Frobenius Theorem although that would be an overkill. ($H$ is a Frobenius Complement of a Frobenius Group $G$.)